# Como volto pra um ponto antes de um merge no GitHub

Tags: git, github, merge

Da uma olhada no gráfico dos meus commits: https://github.com/danieldspx/cni/network

Eu fiz uma cagada aqui, eu queria fazer um merge do branch workspace com o master. O workspace é o que estava mais atual, ai eu queria passar pro master e apagar o workspace branch. So que eu fui tentar fazer o merge e ao tentar resolver o conflito de um arquivo esqueci de tirar a seção:

```
<<<<<<<< HEAD

{Codigo...}

======

{Codigo...}

>>>>>> origin/workspace
```

Eu tentei fazer um revert para antes do merge. Consegui, tanto é que é o meu ultimo commit. Entretanto não consigo fazer o merge desse ultimo commit com o ultimo commit do workspace. Ele diz que já está up-to-date. Eu entendo eu to com commit a frente de workspace , mas é pq eu fiz merda. Como eu conserto isso?

Comment: `git merge --abort`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No repositório local:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^1
```

O comando reset elimina commits, de duas maneiras.
Usando --hard o commit é eliminado definitivamente.

Para eliminar um commit é preciso passar o hash dele, mas nesse caso como é o anterior é possível usar o HEAD.

A notação ^1 é igual a -1, ou seja commit anterior ao HEAD. É possível usar ^2, ^3…^n.

Agora que oncommit foi eliminado é só enviar para o GitHub, usando:

```
git push origin master -f
```

O -f é force, é irá equalizar o repositório remoto com o que está sendo enviado.

Importante: tanto o primeiro e como o segundo comando devem ser usandos com cuidado.
O primeiro é possível "reverter" no repositório local através de reflog, já o segundo alter em definitivo o repositório, e outros usuários clonando o repositório deverão sincronizar as mudanças.

Comment: Como é commit de merge, como que o `reset HEAD^1` sabe para qual dos dois pais ir? Fiquei na dúvida

Comment: Vlw caara funcionou aqui.

Comment: Jefferson, eu fui para o commit do master antes do merge, agora nao da pra ver pois fiz o push no repositorio e o grafico atualizou. Antes de tudo voce roda o git log --oneline --graph ai vai ver on ta o merge, ai vc pega o hash do commit do master antes do merge, ai vc faz `git reset --hard hash_id` depois disso se vc rodar `git log --oneline --graph` vai ver que os commits do outro branch nao vao aparecer pois eles estao em outro branch e vc no master. Caso vc queira mudar de branch use o `git checkout nome_branch`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Talvez isso esclareça sua dúvida: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2222920

Comment: @hkotsubo responde mesmo. Valeu

Answer (score 1):

A resolução do seu problema, permitindo que o merge de branchs funcione novamente, é resolvida apagando o commit de merge da branch `master` e, no seu caso, apagando também o commit de revert.

Mas antes, vou explicar o que ocorreu.

> Consegui, tanto é que é o meu ultimo commit. Entretanto não consigo fazer o merge desse ultimo commit com o ultimo commit do workspace. Ele diz que já está up-to-date.

Isto ocorreu porque seu commit de merge ainda estava lá, mesmo fazendo o `revert`. Veja como ficou seu repositório quando fez o revert, sendo CN os commits na master, `W` o commit da sua branch `workspace`, `CM` o commit de merge e `RE` o seu revert:

```
                   .--D--.                          << workspace
                  /       \
C1<---C2<---C3<--´---------CM<---RE                 << master
```

Se tentar fazer o merge novamente entre workspace e master, veja que o Git entende que o merge já foi feito!

Assim, o ideal é apagar o commit de merge (`CM`) e de revert (`RE`) com:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~2 # apaga os dois últimos commits da master
```

Fazendo com que o repositório fique como estava antes:

```
                   .--D              << workspace
                  /       
C1<---C2<---C3<--´                   << master
```

Permitindo novamente o `merge` entre elas.